# what does "=" mean in a django queryset filter on a ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

I'm not clear from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) what an "=" filter condition means when used directly on a `ManyToManyField`.

For example, if I have:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

What does the `.filter(publications=pub)` do here:

```
pub = Publication.objects.get(id=1) # or any other Publication
Article.objects.filter(publications=pub)
```

- Will it select articles that have exactly/only this publication?
- Will it select articles that have at least this publication, among others?

And what does the `.filter(publications=pubs)` mean here:

```
pubs = Publication.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2]) # or any other subset query of Publication
Article.objects.filter(publications=pubs)
```

- Will it select articles that have exactly/only this subset of publications?
- Will it select articles that have at least all of the publications, among others?
- Will it select articles that have at least one of these publications?

Answer (score 1):

```
pub = Publication.objects.get(id=1) # or any other Publication
Article.objects.filter(publications=pub)
```

This first part means that it will get all articles that are at least related to the publication with id=1.

```
pubs = Publication.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2]) # or any other subset query of Publication
Article.objects.filter(publications=pubs)
```

This second part will get all articles with publications with either id=1 or id=2.

For more information, try the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/).